# The data value could not be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow

Tags: vb.net, informix

I have recently migrated an application from .NET Framework 2.0 to .NET Framework 4.5.  It is using Informix version 3.50 as a database.  After migration, when it is fetching from the database and the fields contain special characters, it is throwing the following error:

> The data value could not be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow. For example, the data was corrupted in the data store but the row was still retrievable".

I am using a `SELECT` query to fill a `DataSet`.  When I run the query manually in database, it gives the results without any issues, but when filling the `DataSet` in the code, I am getting the error.  The non migrated solution is working properly.

Can anyone provide any solution for this. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: A sample of the code where you are executing the query would probably be helpful.

Comment: Could be when you are setting the parameters or when you get the data. We would need to know on which line it isn't working. Sometime, we just need to fill up more information as parameters to the function.

Comment: What do the fields contain before the migration?  3.50 is the version of the client software (Informix Client SDK or Informix Connect) used to connect to the Informix server (which will have a version number such as 11.50 or 11.70 or 12.10 — at least, if you're using a supported or recently supported version).   The error is oddly worded.  Is it just the data access path that is changed or have you changed database server versions

Answer (score 1):

For the .NET Framework 4.x driver support, the minimum recommended version of Informix Client SDK is **CSDK 4.10 xC2 or higher**. The latest is CSDK 4.10 xC12

Answer (score 0):

Error - data value could not be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow.

I downloaded Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable again using the re-install option and issue was fixed